# Symfony 2 - How to print properties in twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

It have two entity in PhotoBundle, one is Photo entity, another one is FileManaged entity. they have ONE-TO-ONE relation.

```
Hy\PhotoBundle\Entity\Photo:
type: entity
oneToOne:
    file_managed:
      targetEntity: FileManaged
      mappedBy: photo
      joinColumn:
        name: photo
        referencedColumnName: fid

Hy\PhotoBundle\Entity\FileManaged:
type: entity
oneToOne:
    photo:
      targetEntity: Photo
      joinColumn:
        name: fid
        referencedColumnName: photo
```

I want to print uri in photo's index.html.twig file, how to print it?

My Code is:

```
{% for entity in pagination %}
{{ entity.title }} <!--Ok-->
{{ entity.file_managed.uri }} <!--Error-->{% endfor %}
```

and it show an error message:

```
Method "file_managed" for object "Hy\PhotoBundle\Entity\Photo" does not exist in HyPhotoBundle:Photo:index.html.twig at line 25
```

What I'm doing wrong?

the pic is using ladybug dump:

```
{{ entity|ladybug_dump }}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxu8X.png

Comment: Do you have getFile_managed() function in your PhotoEntity?

Comment: try fileManaged instead of file_managed if it's an object and not an array

Comment: Why need getFile_managed() function? it can show data using {{ entity|ladybug_dump }}.

Comment: if I using  fileManaged instead of file_managed , it show:Method "fileManaged" for object "Hy\PhotoBundle\Entity\Photo" does not exist in HyPhotoBundle:Photo:index.html.twig at line 25

Comment: In your PhotoEntity you should have setFileManaged and getFileManaged  , getFileManaged returns the related FileManaged object. Does your FileManaged entity have a field called url?

Comment: thank you, it works now, when it have setFileManaged and getFileManaged, but I don't know why need  setFileManaged and getFileManaged, the data can print without setFileManaged and getFileManaged

Comment: The data in the main entity will print but your related entity will not if it can't fetch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PhotoBundle\Entity\Photo entity should look like this. Note it is not fully fleshed out, just the relevant methods.

```
class Photo{

   protected $id;

   protected $file_managed;

   public function setFileManaged($file)
   {

       $this->file_managed = $file;

       return $this;

   }

   public function getFileManaged()
   {

       return $this->file_managed;

   }

}
```

With this you should be able to access entity.fileManaged.url or whatever you defined in your entity inside your twig templates.